# rendering email images in outlook

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

I am making an email template. I gathered that outlook would be quite uncooperative anyway. So have made some exceptions in the design.

However I am generating content via PHP and this retrieve an image from a DB seamlessly.

What I am getting however is the image being rendered like the following:
[image]

(he thin line on the side)

when in Hotmail it appears as a full image.
I have tried CSS such as display block/inline and adding heights and widths to it. I'm guessing its how its being created though.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What I've learned making e-mails for outlook, is don't use background images if you can avoid it and only use inline css. If you use an image tag with a width and height both as attributes and as inline css, it should work... in most mail clients

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you  load in an outlook template, with images and then view source to see how it was done.